# Printing text - Python / Pygame

Tags: text, python-3.x, printing, pygame, blit

Currently I am working on a small 'space invaders' style game using pygame and I wanted to create various outcomes depending on the score / health level. I wish to make it so if the enemy ships have passed the player and go off the screen and the score target has not yet met then I want it to display a message stating the target score has not been met.

I have this code so far which I think should allow this to happen:

```
if block.rect.y >= 600 and health >=25 and score < 70:
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
    label2 = font.render("Score target not met", 1, (0,255,0))
    label2Rect = label.get_rect()
    labelRect.center = (400, 250)
```

Here it is implemented in more depth:

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        laser.play()
        k_space = True

if k_space:
    bullet = Bullet()
    bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
    bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
    all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
    bullet_list.add(bullet)

k_space = False






for player in player_list:

    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

    for block in block_hit_list:
        collision.play()
        block_list.remove(block)
        all_sprites_list.remove(block)
        health -= 25

        if health == 0:
            font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
            label = font.render("GAME OVER", 1, (255,0,0))
            labelRect = label.get_rect()
            labelRect.center = (400, 250)
            gameover.play()
            collision.stop()
            player_list.remove(player)
            all_sprites_list.remove(player)
            break












for bullet in bullet_list:

    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

    for block in block_hit_list:
        explosion.play()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        score += 10

        if health >= 25 and score == 70:
            win.play()
            font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
            label = font.render("LEVEL COMPLETE!", 1, (0,255,0))
            labelRect = label.get_rect()
            labelRect.center = (400, 250)
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            break

    if score >= 70:
        collision.stop()
        laser.stop()
        explosion.stop()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        block_list.remove(block)
        all_sprites_list.remove(block)
        player_list.remove(player)
        all_sprites_list.remove(player)

    if health == 0:
        laser.stop()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    #NOT FUNCTIONING

if block.rect.y >= 600 and health >=25 and score < 70:
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
    label2 = font.render("Score target not met", 1, (0,255,0))
    label2Rect = label.get_rect()
    labelRect.center = (400, 250)

    #NOT FUNCTIONING
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, WHITE)
textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_width()/5)

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
text2 = font.render("Health: " + str(health), True, GREEN)
textpos2 = text2.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_height())

all_sprites_list.update()

screen.blit(background, (0,0))

if label != None: 
        screen.blit(label, labelRect)

if health == 75:
    text2 = font.render("Health: " + str(health), True, YELLOW)
elif health == 50:
    text2 = font.render("Health: " + str(health), True, ORANGE)
elif health == 25:
    text2 = font.render("Health: " + str(health), True, RED)
elif health == 0:
    text = font.render(" ", True, BLACK)
    text2 = font.render(" ", True, BLACK)

if score >= 70:
    text = font.render(" ", True, BLACK)
    text2 = font.render(" ", True, BLACK)

screen.blit(text, textpos)

screen.blit(text2, textpos2)

screen.blit(label, labelRect)

all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

pygame.display.update()

clock.tick(190)

pygame.quit()
```

If anyone has any idea as to why the text isnt printing once the if statement is met id really appreciate the help. Thank you.

---

### UPDATE

I have just realized that the font does in fact get printed to the screen however this only happens if I manage to avoid collisions with all enemy ships and if I dont fire a bullet. Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... It looks to me like you have done everything right. Here is some of my code for blitting text to a screen that I know works:

```
font = pygame.font.Font("Fonts/Typewriter.ttf", 20)
deathCount = font.render("Deaths: "+str(deaths), 1,(255,255,255))
winTally = font.render("Wins: "+str(winCount), 1,(255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(deathCount, (5, 5))
```

Besides that, unless your if statement is not working I'm not sure sorry :/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried your suggestion but still no luck :( I think it might be an issue with the block.rect.y section of the if statement but i'm pretty new to python so i'm not sure!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the block.rect.y and when do you define it?